# PHP multiple criterion/advanced search (for absolute dummies)

Tags: php, search, mysqli

I'd like to have a multiple criterion/advanced search option on my website, but I don't have any clue how to do it. The search should include words, a drop list, and checkboxes.

I have got all the information from my MySQL database listed (https://rajalassie.net/tietokantakokeilu/kanta.php), but I want to make a search form, where a person can select what features she/he wants to see (https://rajalassie.net/tietokantakokeilu/etsi.php)

I'm absolutely novice with this, I don't even know where to start with, so I would really much appreciate if someone would tell me word by word what I should do to make the form works. I have tried to get some hint from older topics/posts here, but I wasn't able to adapt the information.

Not sure if anyone needs this, but this is a code I use when I'm calling all the information from the database.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dogs WHERE aktiivinen='1' ORDER BY country, name";

$haku = $yhteys->query($sql);

if ($haku->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($info = $haku->fetch_assoc()) {

Print "<center><table cellspacing=\"4\"><tr><td colspan=\"4\">".$info["name"].", ".$info["gender"]."</td>";
Print "<td rowspan=\"3\">Source: ";
    if ($info["lahde"] == 'owner') {echo "owner";}
    elseif ($info["lahde"] == 'breeder') {echo "breeder";}
    elseif ($info["lahde"] == 'muu') {echo "another database";}
    elseif ($info["lahde"] == 'joku') {echo "another source";}

Print "<br />Affected: ";
    if ($info["nivel1"] == 'shoulder') {echo "shoulder";}
    elseif ($info["nivel1"] == 'elbow') {echo "elbow";}
    elseif ($info["nivel1"] == 'hock') {echo "hock";}
    elseif ($info["nivel1"] == 'other') {echo "other";}

Print "</td></tr><tr>";

Print "<td colspan=\"2\" width=\"40%\">".$info["sire"]."</td>";
Print "<td colspan=\"2\" width=\"40%\">".$info["dam"]."</td></tr><tr>";
Print "<td width=\"20%\">".$info["siresire"]."</td>";
Print "<td width=\"20%\">".$info["siredam"]."</td>";
Print "<td width=\"20%\">".$info["damsire"]."</td>";
Print "<td width=\"20%\">".$info["damdam"]."</td></tr></table></center>";
```

And here is the form-code

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get" id="search">
<table width="100%" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Dog's name or reg number</td>
        <td>County dog lives in</td>
        <td width="25%">gender</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="25%"><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="40"></td> 
        <td> 
            <form action="/action_page.php">
            <select name="country">
                <option value="all-countries">all countries</option>
                <option value="fi">Finland</option>
                <option value="se">Sweden</option>  
                <option value="no">Norway</option>  
                <option value="dk">Denmark</option> 
            </select>
            </form>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label><input name="sex" type="checkbox" id="male" value="male">male</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <label><input name="sex" type="checkbox" id="female" value="female">female</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Affected joint</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            Shoulder
            <label><input name="sd" type="checkbox" id="sd-left" value="sd-left">left</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <label><input name="sd" type="checkbox" id="sd-right" value="sd-right">right</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <label><input name="sd" type="checkbox" id="sd-both" value="sd-both">both</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />

            Elbow
            <label><input name="elbow" type="checkbox" id="elbow-left" value="elbow-left">left</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <label><input name="elbow" type="checkbox" id="elbow-right" value="elbow-right">right</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <label><input name="elbow" type="checkbox" id="elbow-both" value="elbow-both">both</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />

            Hock
            <label><input name="hock" type="checkbox" id="hock-left" value="hock-left">left</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <label><input name="hock" type="checkbox" id="hock-right" value="hock-right">right</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <label><input name="hock" type="checkbox" id="hock-both" value="hock-both">both</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />

            Else, where?
            <input name="else" type="text" id="else" size="30">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>

<button type="submit" form="search" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: This is rather too broad of a question for this site - we are not here to give full-on beginner’s tutorials. Please go read [ask], and then edit your question accordingly. Explain what you have tried, with what results, and what exactly the remaining problem is.

Comment: [This would give you the idea](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/dynamical_where). Besides, PDO is ten times better than mysqli, so you are supposed to switch anyway and then you'd be able to use this code as is